# Web API, odata v4 and Castle Windsor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection, odata, castle-windsor

I have WebApi project with ODataController and I'm trying to inject some dependency into MyController. I was following this [blogpost](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2012/10/03/DependencyInjectioninASP.NETWebAPIwithCastleWindsor/) by Mark Seemann.

Consider code below.

Problem is, that when is MyController creating, I got exception inside WindsorCompositionRoot Create method on this line,

```
var controller = (IHttpController)this.container.Resolve(controllerType);
```

> An exception of type 'Castle.MicroKernel.ComponentNotFoundException'
>   occurred in Castle.Windsor.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: No component for supporting the service
>   System.Web.OData.MetadataController was found

Any idea how to fix this?
Thank you.

**My controller:**

```
 public class MyController : ODataController
{
    private readonly DataLayer _db;

    public PrepravyController(DataLayer db)
    {
        _db = db;
    }
}
```

**CompositonRoot:**

```
public class WindsorCompositionRoot : IHttpControllerActivator
{
    private readonly IWindsorContainer container;

    public WindsorCompositionRoot(IWindsorContainer container)
    {
        this.container = container;
    }

    public IHttpController Create(
        HttpRequestMessage request,
        HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor,
        Type controllerType)
    {
        var controller =
            (IHttpController)this.container.Resolve(controllerType);

        request.RegisterForDispose(
            new Release(
                () => this.container.Release(controller)));

        return controller;
    }

    private class Release : IDisposable
    {
        private readonly Action release;

        public Release(Action release)
        {
            this.release = release;
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            this.release();
        }
    }
}
```

**Global asax**:

```
 var container = new WindsorContainer();
        container.Install(new RepositoriesInstaller());

        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Services.Replace(typeof(IHttpControllerActivator), new WindsorCompositionRoot(container));
                    GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
```

Comment: Are you sure the "controllerType" at the time you receive this error is of type MyController?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you're registering all your controllers with the container:

```
public class ControllerInstaller : IWindsorInstaller
{
    public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
    {
        container.Register(Classes.FromThisAssembly().BasedOn<IController>().LifestylePerWebRequest())
                 .Register(Classes.FromThisAssembly().BasedOn<ApiController>().LifestylePerWebRequest());
    }
}
```

Windsor uses installers to encapsulate and partition registration logic. It also includes a helper called FromAssembly, so you don't need to manually instantiate all your installers:

```
_container = new WindsorContainer();
_container.Install(FromAssembly.This());
```

Comment: to fix the error you may also need to register the MetadataController from System.Web.OData assembly:

`container.Register(Classes.FromAssembly(Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(System.Web.OData.MetadataController))).BasedOn<System.Web.Http.ApiController>().LifestylePerWebRequest());`

adapted from [https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/issues/711](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/issues/711)